# In .Net Core 2.0 + SQLite EFCore, Concurrency Check not working for 'delete'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, optimistic-concurrency

1. I Created my SQLite DB first, with all the tables in it

   2. I then generated the DbContext and Model Classes (for the Tables) using the Scaffold-DbContext command from the Package Manager Console
   3. I used a column for timestamp and created to SQLite triggers to update it after insert and update ops.  The DATETIME column actually gets created as TEXT in SQLite but that's not the issue here
   4. In the Model Class I decorated the corresponding property (for the DATETIME column) with `[ConcurrencyCheck]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attributes
   5. Now while testing my CRUD ops through my ASP.Net Core RazorPages, I opened one (browser) tab for Edit and another for Delete
   6. I modify the row contents in the Edit-page and save it - works as expected
   7. Now I go to the already opened Delete Page (the displayed contents are obsolete since it's modified in the Edit page, just before) and try to delete it
   8. The record gets successfully deleted whereas I expected a Concurrency Exception

Why is it so?  Am I missing something crucial?  Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions. BTW, I using Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.6.7 (latest) on Windows 10 Pro x64 Build 1709 (with latest updates) and .Net Core 2.1.104

Regards,
Vatsan

### Some additional info from my code

My Table Model Class:

```
[Table("Client_Tags")]
public partial class ClientTags
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    [Display(Name = "Row ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Client_ID", TypeName = "VARCHAR(255)")]
    [Display(Name = "Client ID")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Tag_Name", TypeName = "VARCHAR(255)")]
    [Display(Name = "Tag")]
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    [Column("Last_Updated", TypeName = "DATETIME")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Updated Time")]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string LastUpdated { get; set; }

}
```

Snippet from my DbContext.OnModelCreating() method:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientTags>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ClientId, e.TagName })
                .IsUnique();
        });
```

Snippet from my Delete.cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ClientTag.Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ClientTag.LastUpdated" />"
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

Snippet from my Delete.cshtml.cs:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ErrMsg throwErrMsg = () =>
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(
                    string.Empty,
                    "Error updating the values.  Try again later"
                );
            return Page();
        };

        ClientTag = await _context.ClientTags.FindAsync(id);
        if (ClientTag == null)
        {
            return throwErrMsg();
        }

        try
        {
            _context.ClientTags.Remove(ClientTag);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
        {
            return throwErrMsg();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

-x-x-x-

Answer (score 1):

This question is referenced on this Entity Framework Core [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12260). The issue is marked as **closed** with a working example (and because no more feedback has been provided).

You may also want to check out [this blog post](https://elanderson.net/2018/12/entity-framework-core-sqlite-concurrency-checks/) to see a full implementation and compare to yours.